# Relative directories with subdomains

Tags: html, apache, directory, apache2

So I have domain let's say **domain.com** and the folder of that website is also called domain inside that folder I have a folder called administration which is used for my subdomain **cms.domain.com**

```
  -Domain
      -index
      -css
      -js
      -Administration
           -index
```

And I want to include files from the main directory inside of index in administration with ../css/something.css resulting in 404 (Not Found)

I first test new things on my local server and then send it to deployment and I don't want to change include names everytime I'm making a change in files and when I have to upload it.

This is a regular subdomain (not done through htaccess) I've added A name in  DNS on my server and also added cms.domain.conf in Vhost

Answer (score 0):

Use sym-links on your server to make the files or folders appear in both locations in your file system.

You haven't stated your OS. Assuming it might be linux based and that your upload tool can preserve symlinks (rsync):

```
cd Domain
ln -s Administration/css css
```

Comment: yes it is linux, regular ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to access files with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] but my subdomain folder doesn't have  access to root for some reason. I probably have to fix permissions somehow.

Comment: Hmm, if the main domain can access files, then it probably isn't a file system permissions issue. Perhaps you should post the host config from apache. This is probably the `<VirtualHost>` sections if you have multiple domains on one apache server.